# Can't enable apache mod_proxy module on mac os x

Tags: macos, apache, apache-modules

Trying to enable **proxy** module for apache on the mac os x system (latest version - catalina 10.15.5). However, after uncommenting the lines

> LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
> LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
> LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so

in the `httpd.conf` to load the proxy module, and running

```
/usr/sbin/apachectl -V
```

getting the error:

> httpd: Syntax error on line 137 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Cannot load libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_connect.so into server: dlopen(/usr/libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_connect.so, 10): Symbol not found: _ap_proxy_checkproxyblock2\n  Referenced from: /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_connect.so\n  Expected in: flat namespace\n in /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_connect.so

> Server version: Apache/2.4.41 (Unix)

Files exist at the given location and it is not the permission issue (tested different ways, even copied files to different locations):

[image: screenshot]

It seems a dead end.

How to fix the issue or how to enable apache proxy module for mac os x?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like mod_proxy compatibility issue. are you using compile Apache httpd or rpm base Apache httpd?

Comment: @Pandurang I'm using the mac os default apache web server, also tried to reinstall it, missing anything here?

Comment: I am not sure about mac os but for centos, the proxy module comes with Apache HTTPD. Only need to add ProxyPass configuration.